# How to place a TextView on top of a ImageVew in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout, visible, depth-buffer

I am using a ConstraintLayout and I want to place a TextView on top of an ImageView.

But I'm not able to find this feature in the ConstraintLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.sayani.myApp.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/image1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="240dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the above code the TextView is hidden under the ImageView.
How can I place the text on top of the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your app has a minimum SDK of 21 or higher, you can add this to whichever UI element you want to appear above the other: `android:elevation="4dp"`

Doesn't have to be 4dp, it can be higher or lower depending on what works in your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `bringToFront()` function which works on pre-api 21:

```
TextView myTextView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
myTextView.bringToFront();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you in the XML **add the TextView below the ImageView** (like you have done) then it **will appear on top** of the ImageView. Consequently if you add it before it will appear below the ImageView.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/image1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:text="TextView on top of an ImageView" />
```

If you want it centered vertically on the screen then you could use

> app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
> app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"